# AzerothCore: how to convert a zone to a Sanctuary

Tags: azerothcore

Recently I had to look at a solution on how to convert a zone to make it a "Sanctuary" type one.
The idea was to run an event on one of the unused zones of the game to do not allow people to fight each other without a duel request.

So is it possible to do it without changing the DBC files?

Answer (score 0):

With AzerothCore it is definitely possible!

AzerothCore doesn't rely only on DBC files but it has database tables to override all of them.

I wrote a guide on the wiki for it: https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/how-to-import-dbc-data-in-db